# If/Else in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
 $(function () {
                // answer choosing event
                $('.radio').on('change', function(e) {
                        while(suma<5)
                        {   
                            if (suma==1) {
                            // change question
                                        $('h1').text('#2.Q2 ?');
                                        var label1 = $("label[for=radio1]");
                                        var label2 = $("label[for=radio2]");
                                        var label3 = $("label[for=radio3]");
                                        var label4 = $("label[for=radio4]");
                                        document.getElementById('radio1').checked=false;
                                        //change label text
                                        label1.text("11");
                                        label2.text("22");
                                        label3.text("33");
                                        label4.text("44");
                                        suma = 2;
                        }                               
                        else if (suma==2) {
                            // schimbare intrebare
                                        $('h1').text('#3.Q3?');
                                        var label1 = $("label[for=radio1]");
                                        var label2 = $("label[for=radio2]");
                                        var label3 = $("label[for=radio3]");
                                        var label4 = $("label[for=radio4]");
                                        document.getElementById('radio1').checked=false;
                                        //change label text
                                        label1.text("111");
                                        label2.text("222");
                                        label3.text("333");
                                        label4.text("444");
                                        suma = 3;
                            } 
                            else {
                            // schimbare intrebare
                                        $('h1').text('#4.Q4?');
                                        var label1 = $("label[for=radio1]");
                                        var label2 = $("label[for=radio2]");
                                        var label3 = $("label[for=radio3]");
                                        var label4 = $("label[for=radio4]");
                                        document.getElementById('radio1').checked=false;
                                        //change label text
                                        label1.text("11111");
                                        label2.text("22222");
                                        label3.text("33333");
                                        label4.text("44444");
                                        suma++;
                            }

                        }






                        });
                     });
```

Why does it follow the last case when I press a button? It should go to the case when sum==2.
So whenever it detects a change in the state of a checkbox/button, it does those things, it increments the sum and goes to the next case. But my code follows the last else directly.

Comment: You're looking for arrays.

Comment: I mean, when I choose an answer, it gets to the next question and answers. Can it be done?

Comment: <script>
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cars[0];
</script>

can I use some functions instead of saab volvo etc?

Comment: Huh? You can call a function wherever you like.

Comment: Where does the suma value get initialized or changed, especially after the code that handles the button event?

Comment: It gets initialized just before the document ready function. After choosing an answer it is incremented by 1.